# Getting data from mongodb in nodejs

Tags: mongodb, node.js

Does the action of getting data from mongo a blocking operation in node (if done incorrectly ?). What is the best way to make a query and also what should i avoid.I am using mongoosejs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Andrei, Node makes synchronous & blocking stuff really hard to do, so don't worry so much. I advise you read the official documentation from Mongoose and then take a look at the [Nodepad](https://github.com/alexyoung/nodepad) application developed by Alex Young.

The tutorials for that application can be found here: http://dailyjs.com/tags.html#nodepad

Also in general, Mongoose & Node code usually look like this:

```
database.query(conditions, function(error, data) {
  if (error) { throw error; return; }
  // do stuff with your data here
});
```

Other useful resources:

[Is there any good MongooseDB Tutorial / example website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5784670/is-there-any-good-mongoosedb-tutorial-example-website) 
Video presentations on Node.js & MongoDB from 10gen's official website: http://www.10gen.com/presentations#programming_lang__javascript_nodejs 
http://nodenerd.net/post/4926637100/quick-hit-mongoose-js 
http://blog.mongodb.org/post/6587009156/cloudfoundry-mongodb-and-nodejs